# Find The Bounding Box From A Set Of Geopoints Mapbox

Tags: java, android, mapbox

I'm trying to find bounding box from a collection of GeoPoints but it is not zooming to properly. I'm pasting the function which I used to find the bounding box below

```
private BoundingBox createBoundingBox(final ArrayList<LatLng> list){
        double minLatitude = 90, minLongitiude = 180, maxLatitude = -90, maxLongitude = -180;
        double currentLat, currentLng;
        for(LatLng location : list){
            currentLat    = location.getLatitude();
            currentLng    = location.getLongitude();
            minLatitude   = Math.max(minLatitude, currentLat);
            minLongitiude = Math.max(minLongitiude, currentLng);
            maxLatitude   = Math.min(maxLatitude, currentLat);
            maxLongitude  = Math.min(maxLongitude, currentLng);
        }
       return new BoundingBox(minLatitude, minLongitiude, maxLatitude - minLatitude,
               maxLongitude - minLongitiude);
}
```

Can anybody suggest me what I'm doing wrong here. The map zoom level is still 0.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Looks like you're on the right path, but your default mins and maxes are causing some trouble.  Give the following a try:

```
public BoundingBox findBoundingBoxForGivenLocations(ArrayList<LatLng> coordinates)
{
    double west = 0.0;
    double east = 0.0;
    double north = 0.0;
    double south = 0.0;

    for (int lc = 0; lc < coordinates.size(); lc++)
    {
        LatLng loc = coordinates.get(lc);
        if (lc == 0)
        {
            north = loc.getLatitude();
            south = loc.getLatitude();
            west = loc.getLongitude();
            east = loc.getLongitude();
        }
        else
        {
            if (loc.getLatitude() > north)
            {
                north = loc.getLatitude();
            }
            else if (loc.getLatitude() < south)
            {
                south = loc.getLatitude();
            }
            if (loc.getLongitude() < west)
            {
                west = loc.getLongitude();
            }
            else if (loc.getLongitude() > east)
            {
                east = loc.getLongitude();
            }
        }
    }

    // OPTIONAL - Add some extra "padding" for better map display
    double padding = 0.01;
    north = north + padding;
    south = south - padding;
    west = west - padding;
    east = east + padding;

    return new BoundingBox(north, east, south, west);
}
```

Comment: Hey @Brad Leege, Can you tell me how to add custom background for the tool tip of a marker.

Comment: Thanks @brad-leege! Why after that centered user location?

Comment: Use the method above to find the bounding box by passing your set of GeoCoordinates in an arraylist to the function it will return you the BoundingBox so that u can set it on the map

Comment: double west = 0.0;//maxX
double east = 0.0;//minX
              
 double north = 0.0; //maxY
double south = 0.0;//minY  correct?

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin solution. Improvement over @Pulkit Goyal

```
private fun zoomToMultipleGeoCoordinates(boundingList: List<GeoCoordinates>, isPaddingRequired: Boolean) {
    var north = Double.MIN_VALUE
    var south = Double.MAX_VALUE
    var east = Double.MIN_VALUE
    var west = Double.MAX_VALUE

    boundingList.forEach { loc ->
        north = loc.latitude.coerceAtLeast(north)
        south = loc.latitude.coerceAtMost(south)
        west = loc.longitude.coerceAtMost(west)
        east = loc.longitude.coerceAtLeast(east)
    }

    if (isPaddingRequired) {
        val padding = 0.01
        north += padding
        south -= padding
        west -= padding
        east += padding
    }
 return BoundingBox.fromLngLats(west, south, east, north)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is [@Brad Leege's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26939834/643109) for ported to Kotlin with minor improvements:

```
fun findEnclosingBoundingBox(coordinates: ArrayList<LatLng>): BoundingBox {
    var west = GeometryConstants.MAX_LONGITUDE
    var east = GeometryConstants.MIN_LONGITUDE
    var north = GeometryConstants.MIN_LATITUDE
    var south = GeometryConstants.MAX_LATITUDE

    coordinates.forEach { loc ->
        north = Math.max(loc.latitude, north)
        south = Math.min(loc.latitude, south)
        west = Math.min(loc.longitude, west)
        east = Math.min(loc.longitude, east)
    }

    // Add some extra "padding"
    val padding = 0.01
    north += padding
    south -= padding
    west -= padding
    east += padding

    return BoundingBox.fromLngLats(west, south, east, north)
}
```

Comment: You made a copy-paste error here.`east` should be `Math.max(loc.longitude, east)`